# Mouse movement vertical axis inversion? (Mac OS X)

Tags: mac, terminal, mouse, applescript, axis

I would like to either run an AppleScript or use a Terminal command to invert the y-axis for mouse movement in OSX— and no, not like http://d.pr/w9z7 (/joke). Any ideas? I thought about checking for mouse position and doing some math subtracting that from screen-height or something, but that seems not very efficient, and plus, I'm not up on the syntax (heh). Help?

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure that AppleScript will be insufficient since it's not designed to be able to catch all mouse movement, and the use of Terminal would be predicated on that code existing in the operating system in the first place. If it is, I'm not aware of it.

What I might try is installing a 3rd party mouse driver, for example [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/), and using that to invert the y-axis as you wish.

Comment: Just checked it out--USB Overdrive can in fact do this in Advanced Settings.

Answer (score 0):

As of today 2023-10-02, the beta of Karabiner Elements can do this. I'm typing this on a machine where I've used this successfully. It works perfectly as far as I can tell.